# I'm making a authentication login form then I face this error

Tags: flutter, validation, dart, error-handling

I'm making authentication login form and want to connect `submitAuthForm Function` to the `AuthForm`. That's why I pass reference in the `AuthForm`. I am beginner. Please help me to solve this problem (The argument type `void Function(String, String, String, bool)` can't be assigned to the parameter type `void Function(String, String, String, bool)`

Thanks.

```
class AuthScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  

  @override
  _AuthScreenState createState() => _AuthScreenState();
}

class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {
  void _submitAuthForm(
      String email, 
      String password, 
      String username, 
      bool isLogin) {

      }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        body: Authform(_submitAuthForm,)/*( The argument type 'void Function(String, String, String, bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Void Function(String, String, String, bool)'.*/)
        );
  }
}

class Authform extends StatefulWidget {
  
  Authform(this.submitFN);

  final Void Function(
      String email, String password, String username, bool isLogin) submitFN;

  @override
  _AuthformState createState() => _AuthformState();
}

class _AuthformState extends State<Authform> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var _isLogin = true;
  var _userEmail;
  var _userName;
  var _userPassword;

  void _trySubmit() {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    if (isValid) {
      _formKey.currentState!.save();
      widget.submitFN(_userEmail,_userPassword,_userName,_isLogin);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    key: ValueKey('email'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                        return 'please enter valid email address';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.mail,
                          color: Colors.orange,
                        ),
                        labelText: 'Email Addess'),
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _userEmail = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  if (!_isLogin)
                    TextFormField(
                      key: ValueKey('username'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 4) {
                          return 'Username is short enter atleast 4 characters ';
                        }
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.person,
                            color: Colors.orange,
                          ),
                          labelText: 'Username'),
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _userName = value;
                      },
                    ),
                  TextFormField(
                    key: ValueKey('password'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 7) {
                        return 'Password must be atleast 7 characters long';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.lock,
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                      labelText: 'password',
                    ),
                    obscureText: true,
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _userPassword = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 12,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: _trySubmit,
                    child: Text(_isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Signup'),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(onPrimary: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _isLogin = !_isLogin;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Text(_isLogin
                          ? 'Create new account'
                          : 'I already have a acoount'))
                ],
              )),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When declaring a function or variable you have follow proper declaring `method` to avoid `unusual` issues. You have declare your `function` using `Void` the `V` is in `capital case` there but it must be in `small case` like `void`. Juts change this like :

```
final Void Function(
```

to

```
final void Function(
```

Comment: Pleased to help you mark it as answer if it worked for you and upvote also. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: AuthScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class AuthScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthScreenState createState() => _AuthScreenState();
}

class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {
  void _submitAuthForm(
      String email, String password, String username, bool isLogin) {}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        body: Authform(
          _submitAuthForm,
        ));
  }
}

class Authform extends StatefulWidget {
  Authform(this.submitFN);

  final void Function(
      String email, String password, String username, bool isLogin) submitFN;

  @override
  _AuthformState createState() => _AuthformState();
}

class _AuthformState extends State<Authform> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var _isLogin = true;
  var _userEmail;
  var _userName;
  var _userPassword;

  void _trySubmit() {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    if (isValid) {
      _formKey.currentState!.save();
      widget.submitFN(_userEmail, _userPassword, _userName, _isLogin);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    key: ValueKey('email'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                        return 'please enter valid email address';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.mail,
                          color: Colors.orange,
                        ),
                        labelText: 'Email Addess'),
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _userEmail = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  if (!_isLogin)
                    TextFormField(
                      key: ValueKey('username'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 4) {
                          return 'Username is short enter atleast 4 characters ';
                        }
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.person,
                            color: Colors.orange,
                          ),
                          labelText: 'Username'),
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _userName `enter code here`= value;
                      },
                    ),
                  TextFormField(
                    key: ValueKey('password'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 7) {
                        return 'Password must be atleast 7 characters long';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.lock,
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                      labelText: 'password',
                    ),
                    obscureText: true,
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _userPassword = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 12,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: _trySubmit,
                    child: Text(_isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Signup'),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(onPrimary: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _isLogin = !_isLogin;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Text(_isLogin
                          ? 'Create new account'
                          : 'I already have a acoount'))
                ],
              )),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

account_screen.dart

```
 child: AuthForm(
    submitFn: _submitAuthForm,
 ),
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?